# Issue using supervisor and uwsgi in conda env

Tags: flask, uwsgi, supervisord

I'm trying to run a Flask app with uwsgi + supervisor + nginx.

uwsgi is installed in a conda env, and I can run my app with no issue without supervisor, i.e. if I run (with my conda env activated):

```
uwsgi --ini /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
```

with the following config:

**/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 666
socket = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.sock
module = wsgi
callable = app
```

**vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/myflaskapp**

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.sock;
    }
}
```

Now I create a supervisor config file:

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/uwsgi-myflaskapp.conf**

```
[program:uwsgi-myflaskapp]
command=/home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin/uwsgi /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/log/uwsgi-myflaskapp.log
redirect_stderr=true
exitcodes=0
```

I start supervisor (installed system-wide) with

```
sudo service supervisor start
```

and load the conf file with

```
sudo supervisorctl reload
```

but I get the following error in the log file:

```
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

Any suggestion?

Here's the complete log:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Mon Jan 11 19:12:14 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 11 January 2016 10:54:59
os: Linux-3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015
nodename: roquefort
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 63047
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x18001e0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ImportError: No module named wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 24671, cores: 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the the path of the wsgi.py file in `/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini` with

```
chdir = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp
```

so that it can now find wsgi.

Comment: If you want to point to a new question that has arisen based on this one, please do so in the comments instead of as part of your answer. As you can see, this makes the answer look like a new question, which is not allowed on this site.