# How to set a conda env with uwsgi and supervisor?

Tags: flask, uwsgi, supervisord, conda

I'm trying to run a Flask app using a conda env with uwsgi and supervisor.

I managed to solve a [first issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34728434/326849) regarding the path of the wsgi script, but I cannot find how to set the conda env.

My uwsgi config file `/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini` is

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi
master = true
process = 2
chmod-socket = 666
chdir = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp
socket = /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/run/myflaskapp.sock
callable = app
vacuum = true
```

and my supervisor config is

```
[program:uwsgi-myflaskapp]
command=/home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin/uwsgi /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/log/uwsgi-myflaskapp.log
redirect_stderr=true
exitcodes=0
```

When I start uwsgi through supervisor I get

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from myflaskapp import app
  File "./myflaskapp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

So I guess I the conda env is not set. How can I set it?

Answer (score 4):

I had to set PATH in my supervisor config file

```
environment=PATH=/home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the -H tag when starting uwsgi from the command line to set the Python path

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#virtualenv

So in your case, in the supervisor config, change your command to:

```
command=/home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin/uwsgi -H /path/to/your/virtualenv /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini
```

You can find your virtualenv path with

```
which python
```

On the command line with your virtualenv activated.

Comment: Maybe you could try activating the venv with supervisor before executing uwsgi? For example:

`command = . /path/to/venv/bin/activate && /home/me/Development/miniconda/envs/myflaskapp/bin/uwsgi /home/me/Development/flask/myflaskapp/myflaskapp.ini`

Comment: The problem is that conda's activate script requires a parameter (environment name), even the ones inside non-root environments, so uwsgi will try to call the activate script without the parameter and it will fail.

Comment: i think u should set env like this: . activate myEnv

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late but this should also work

`command=bash -c "source /path_to_conda/bin/activate && source activate env_name && program_to_run --config=config_path command"`